# Conditionally render an image or a video in React

Tags: reactjs, conditional-rendering

so I have a form to let the user upload an image OR a video. Both fields have a default image.
I've tried different approaches to render whatever the user uploaded (image or video), but nothing has worked as expected:It's like the second part of the conditional was ignored, only image is displayed.
This is the part of my current code related to the conditional rendering:

```js
const Post = (props) => {
  const {
    id,
    owner,
    profile_id,
    profile_image,
    title,
    content,
    image,
    video,
    updated_on,
    postPage,
  } = props;

return (
    <Card className={styles.Post}>
      <Card.Body>
        <Media className="align-items-center justify-content-between">
          <Link to={`/profiles/${profile_id}`}>
            <Avatar src={profile_image} height={55} /> {owner}
          </Link>
          <div className="d-flex align-items-center">
            <span>
              {updated_on}
              {is_owner && postPage && "..."}
            </span>
          </div>
        </Media>
      </Card.Body>
      <div>
          {image ? (
          <Link to={`/posts/${id}`}>
            <Card.Img src={image} alt={title} />                       
          </Link>
         ) : (
          <Link to={`/posts/${id}`}>
            <video src={video} width={400} height={400} controls /> 
          </Link>
        )}
      </div>
```

Comment: What's effectively rendered in the browser when running? Check the devtools around the place where the video should be and check what's really there. Maybe the problem is the video source but the control is there.

Comment: If I open devtools I see the fetched post from the api in the console. I've tested with both type of posts: post with image and post with video and in both cases the image is rendered in the UI.

Comment: Ok, that means that the conditional always takes the "image" path, which means that the `image` prop is never empty, even in the case of a video. This could mean that the parent of this component is passing it the wrong props or the condition for the conditional is wrong here and you would need another way to tell if it's an image or a video.

Answer (score 0):

Make a state variable `isImage` using the `useState` hook. The `isImage` state determines whether to render an image or a video.

```
const [isImage, setIsImage] = useState(true);

// Function to toggle between image and video
const toggleMedia = () => {
  setIsImage(!isImage);
};
{isImage ? (
   imagetag with its src
) : (
   videotag with its src and type
```

A button tag inside which we conditionally renders the video or image

```
{isImage ? 'Show Video' : 'Show Image'}
```

Also inside the button tag use `onClick` with togglemedia function we made

Comment: I don't think that's what's being asked. Nowhere in the question a toogle is mentioned, and the question has a means of telling if you want to display an image or a video.

Comment: Thanks Yash Tiwari, but in fact, I don't need a button in there. I'm building a  small social media, so what I'm trying to do is like the feed on instagram. You call a post by its id and then the post is rendered in the UI. The stuff here is that the user could upload a picture or a video so I have to conditionally bring what is the database.

Comment: you can do  something like this
const Post = ({ post }) => {
  const { mediaType, mediaUrl, caption } = post;

  return (
    <div className="post">
      {mediaType === 'image' ? (
        <img src={mediaUrl} alt="Post Image" />
      ) : mediaType === 'video' ? (
        <video controls>
          <source src={mediaUrl} type="video/mp4" />
          {/* You can add more source tags for different video formats */}
          Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>
      ) : null}
      <p>{caption}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Post;

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).